# Count by bin and type but also get total aggregate in timechart

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a list of events, each event has a type. I want to create a timechart that shows me the events by type per day but also the total number of events per day.

So for example if have

```
5/15 - Soccer
5/15 - Soccer
5/15 - Golf
5/16 - Golf
```

The chart I want needs to show on 5/15 a line for soccer at 2, a line for golf at 1, and a line for ALL at 3 (2+1)

The following query gives me the events by eventtype per day, how do I add the aggregate to it?

```
MyEvents
| summarize count() by bin(TIMESTAMP, 1d), EventType
| render timechart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try either of the following options, using the [`union` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator):

```
MyEvents
| summarize count() by bin(TIMESTAMP, 1d), EventType
| union (
    MyEvents
    | summarize count() by bin(TIMESTAMP, 1d), EventType = "All"
)
| render timechart
```

```
MyEvents
| summarize count() by bin(TIMESTAMP, 10m), EventType
| as hint.materialized = true T
| union (
    T
    | summarize count_ = sum(count_) by TIMESTAMP, EventType = "All"
)
| render timechart
```